# Fragment "refresh" android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to build an Android and I have a fragment `Fragment_X` in wich I read the response from the server (data of the user who logged in) and then create a table.

The fragment isn't the first to show up when the activity starts.

After the login if I select the `Fragment_X` the table doesn't show up, I have to click on it another time and finally the table appears.

Is there a way to make it appear at the first time I select the `Fragment_X`?

Here is my code:

**Fragment_X**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ordini, container, false);

    connection = new DBConnection(c.getId(), getContext());
    connection.downloadOrdiniUtente();
    CookieO cookieO = new CookieO();
    File ordini = new File(path);
    if (ordini.exists()) {
        createTable(cookieO.getOrdini(), v);
    }


    return v;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to know what the problem is without all the other classes methods here you've not shown. Please see about a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wait at least for 500ms when fragment created. After onCreateVeiw wait for 500ms and then make a table. for example

```
onCreateView() {
View view = ............

ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity);
dialog.setMessage("Wait Please");
dialog.show();

new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // here u can display your table
                         showTable();
                         dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        },500);

return view;
}
```

Comment: Why run the action after 500ms? Surely the action should start onCreateView

Comment: naver load data in onCreateView, so when onCreateView completes, then start to loading data and display the data, so you can display table onResume() function

Comment: Okay, then onViewCreated. My point is that I don't see why the TimerTask is completely necessary when the question states data is received but not displayed until touched

Comment: @MubasharJaved I don't know why, but your solution works! Maybe it's not the best way to do it, but at least it works! Thanks!!

Comment: @MubasharJaved Do you know if there is a way to show a sort of "loading message" during the 500ms of wait?